# How to fix 'No pubspec.yaml file found' when flutter project in OneDrive folder?

Tags: flutter

Run `flutter packages get` or `flutter run` in the root of my project, and it prompts the following

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
exit code 1
```

This problem only appears in the project located under the **OneDrive folder**.

**I can run flutter projects elsewhere.**

I want to know if someone has the same problem.

---

After I reinstalled win10 today, this problem disappeared. So I guess this is my personal reason.

Comment: I had the same problem. It worked when I created the app in a folder outside OneDrive

Comment: @Leandro I still don't know why projects can work in OneDrive after I reinstall Win10.

Comment: @Leandro ,I think , folder named "OneDrive" is a reserved word for Windows O/s . So this isn't working . Ha Ha Ha... I will this issues. Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53392) filed related to your issue. And current status is still open. But there is a workaround to fix this.

The author have been able to [resolve the error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53392#issuecomment-605355893) when the app was moved out from "OneDrive"

> Yayy! It worked fine when I moved it out of OneDrive folder. So while
> in OneDrive, it works fine until you touch pubspec.yaml. Anyways, all
> good now!

There is a possibility that the team is still working on the issue.